# Reactor Kafka Junit Testing

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, reactor

So here i'm facing an issue while writing Junit's for Reactor Kafka:

i wrote   :
when(ArgumentMatchers.any()).thenReturn(Mono.just(message));

so i'm getting Response from Mono.just()
but how to test kafkaSender.send(Mono.just(message)) --this snippet ? i kept that Also in when and then but i'm getting exception there... let me know how to Set the       `Flux<SenderResult<String,String,Map<String,String>>> fluxValue` in Junit.....as send method Returns `Flux<Sender<String,String,Map<String,String>>>`

```
Map<String, String> contextMetaData = new HashedMap();
            SenderRecord<String, String, Map<String, String>> message = SenderRecord.create(
                    new ProducerRecord<>("exampleTopic" id, topicdata),
                    contextMetaData);
            kafkaSender.send(Mono.just(message)).then().doOnError(error -> {
                throw new BusinessException(ERROR_PUBLISHING_MESSAGE.getCode(), error.getMessage(),
                        Severity.NON_RETRIABLE,
                        ConfigReader.getInstance().getAsString(Constants.SELF_SOURCE_SYSTEM),
                        error.getCause());
            }).doOnSuccess(s -> {
                logger.info(
                        "Message Sent Successfully to " + "example"+ " TOPIC...");
            }).doOnCancel(() -> close()).doOnNext(r -> {
                logger.trace("Successfully stored ");
            }).subscribe();
        }
```